# Hibernate version mismatch in WildFly 10.0

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly-10

I have 2 projects, one is a normal java project (with maven): `core`, and the other is non-maven dynamic web project: `webapi`. The later acts as a rest layer on top of `core`.

`core` uses hibernate without any problem. It defines the `persistence.xml` (inside `src/META-INF/`) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="app" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>data.entities.Anything</class>
        <class>data.entities.Something</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AppDb"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="****"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="dbo"></property>           
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"></property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

`webapi` uses `core` and try to expose `core`'s functionality as service. I have added `core` to both "Java Build Path", and "Deployment Assembly" of `webapi`. As I am using SQL Server, `sqljdbc42.jar` is also added to "Deployment Assembly" of `webapi`.

However, when I try to deploy `webapi` in WildFly 10.0, the hibernate entity manager is not instantiated properly. My primary suspect here the version mismatch of hibernate-core in `core`, and `webapi`. `core` uses `hibernate-core 5.2.4.Final`, whereas for `webapi` it is coming from WildFly runtime, which is `5.0.7.Final`. This can be seen from the logs below:

- `core` log:

  > [HibernateManager.:19] - Trying to create entityManager for persistence-unit: app
  >
  > [LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation:31] - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
  >   name: app
  >   ...]
  >
  > [Version.logVersion:45] - **HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.4.Final}**
  >
  > [Environment.:213] - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
  >
  > [Environment.buildBytecodeProvider:318] - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
  >
  > [JavaReflectionManager.:66] - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
  >
  > [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure:70] - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
  >
  > [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator:126] - HHH10001005: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AppDb]
  >
  > [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator:135] - HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=****, password=****}
  >
  > [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator:140] - HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
  >
  > [PooledConnections.:41] - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
  >
  > [Dialect.:153] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
  >
  > [Version.:30] - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.3.Final
  >
  > [DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection:47] - HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@19ccca5] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
  >
  > [HibernateManager.:22] - Created entityManager for persistence-unit: app
  >
  > [QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator.initiateService:47] - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
- `webapi` log:

  > [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for app
  >
  > [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'webapi.war#app'
  >
  > [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
  >   name: app
  >   ...]
  >
  > [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) **HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.7.Final}**
  >
  > [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
  >
  > [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
  >
  > [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HHH90000001: Found usage of deprecated setting for specifying Scanner [hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner]; use [hibernate.archive.scanner] instead
  >
  > [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
  >
  > [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 6.0)
  >
  > [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = webapi.war_com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver_6_0
  >
  > [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'webapi.war#app'
  >
  > [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
  >
  > [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) Envers integration enabled? : true
  >
  > [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.3.Final
  >
  > [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
  >
  > **[org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HHH000262: Table not found: Anythings**
  >
  > **[org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) HHH000262: Table not found: Somethings**
  >
  > [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /webapi
  >
  > [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "webapi.war" (runtime-name : "webapi.war")

How this can be rectified?

Comment: Follow up question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997491/org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlexception-schema-dbo-not-found

Comment: While it's not a problem, you might want to use the JPA 2.1 persistence xml definition, since you're using Hibernate 5+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved by changing the version of your Hibernate core in Wildfly. In order to do so, change your META-INF/persistence.xml file like this :

```
<properties>
    <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2" />
    ...
</properties>
```

To add some micro version:

```
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2.4.Final" />
```

Courtesy link : http://in.relation.to/2016/07/07/updating-hibernate-orm-in-wildfly/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to be working, as after the said changes (installing the hibernate 5.2.4 module in widfly, and adding the property in persistence.xml), the error is gone now. However, I am facing another issue; I think, I'll post another question for that.

Comment: Follow up question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997491/org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlexception-schema-dbo-not-found, just in case you are interested