# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "DBO" not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly, sqljdbc

This is a follow up question of [Hibernate version mismatch in WildFly 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996077/hibernate-version-mismatch-in-wildfly-10-0).

For completeness, restating the problem briefly. I have 2 projects, one is a normal java project (with maven): `core`, and the other is non-maven dynamic web project: `webapi`. The later acts as a rest layer on top of `core`.

`core` uses hibernate without any problem. It defines the `persistence.xml` (inside `src/META-INF/`) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="app" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>data.entities.Anything</class>
        <class>data.entities.Something</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AppDb"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="****"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="dbo"></property>           
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"></property>
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2.4.Final" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Both `core` and `webapi` is now using `hibernate-core 5.2.4.Final`, using maven, and WildFly module installation as described [here](http://in.relation.to/2016/07/07/updating-hibernate-orm-in-wildfly/), respectively.

However, now when I deploy `webapi` to WildFly 10.0, I get the following error:

> [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "webapi.war" (runtime-name: "webapi.war")
>
> [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for app
>
> [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'webapi.war#app'
>
> [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>       name: app
>       ...]
>
> [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH90000001: Found usage of deprecated setting for specifying Scanner [hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner]; use [hibernate.archive.scanner] instead
>
> [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 6.0)
>
> [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = webapi.war_com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver_6_0
>
> [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'webapi.war#app'
>
> [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
>
> [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) Envers integration enabled? : true
>
> [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) **GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement**
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:524)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:273)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:203)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:177)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:66)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:877)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
>       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
>
> **Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "DBO" not found; SQL statement:
>   create table dbo.Anythings (Id binary(255) not null, CreatedOn datetime not null, IsActive bit, primary key (Id)) [90079-173]**
>       at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
>       at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
>       at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)
>       at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:616)
>       at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:623)
>       at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5302)
>       at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:3873)
>       at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:324)
>       at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
>       at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
>       at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218)
>       at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:428)
>       at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:377)
>       at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
>       at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:168)
>       at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:156)
>       at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.execute(WrappedStatement.java:198)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
>       ... 20 more

Is there anyway this can be corrected?

**Update:** I think, it is not able to connect the database. When I use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` as `validate` instead of `update`, I get the following error:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [dbo.Anythings]

**Additional info:** I have already placed `sqljdbc42.jar` in `wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft\sqlserver\main`, and the `module.xml` looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- JDBC Drivers module.xml file to configure your JDBC drivers-->

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver" slot="main">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc42.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

I also tried to add `sqlserver` as global subsystem in `standalone.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
    <global-modules>
        <module name="com.microsoft.sqlserver" slot="main"/>
    </global-modules>
...
</subsystem>
```

However, none of these worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be caused by the way how you specify DB connection. On EE environment, you are supposed to use data source definition, either specified as `jta-data-source` or `non-jta-data-source` in your `persistence.xml`. As stated in JPA 2.1 spec(ch. 8.2.1.5), if you do not specify any of them, your wildfly will deploy your app using its default datasource - named ExampleDS - which uses h2 in-memory DB. The connection parameters via properties(`javax.persistence.jdbc.url` etc) are ignored as they are intended for Java SE environment not Java EE.
You need to either add a new datasource definition to the wildfly configuration(standalone.xml or domain.xml depending on your setup) or provide the datasource definition within your app as a file named `<something>-ds.xml` located at `WEB-INF` folder. In both cases, you need to setup your MSSQL driver correctly(deploy to modules, add `module.xml` and add the driver definition to widlfly config /subsytem=datasources). These operations can also be done via jboss-cli interface to avoid manual edits of the configuration file. 
After that remove the connection properties from your persistence.xml and add the jta/non-jta-data-source element with the jndi name of your newly created DS. Also, please remove the global definition of your mssql module

This links might be useful for you:
[Wildfly Hibernate + In app datasource definition](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/11.x/hibernate5)
[JBoss DB Driver+Data source definition via cli](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. As I understand, if I remove the `properties`, then the `core` part of the application will not work in standalone fashion. Is there a way to make both work?

Comment: Why would you need to make it running in both SE and EE? If your app contains other managed components like EJBs. etc that it will now work without EE container of some sorts. Technically, the properties should be ignored by your EE container and honored in SE, if that does not work, you can try to manualy create `Datasource` in your SE env and deploy it under the same JNDI name as in jBoss.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that one of the URL's referenced no longer works, it's now [Wildfly Hibernate + In app datasource definition](https://developers.redhat.com/quickstarts/eap/hibernate5/) - btw, I'm having a similar issue as the "question"